# Astronaut rescues corrupted wife from hell

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror

It was a live action film set in the US, I saw it about 20 years ago on TV.

I do not recall anyone famous being in it.

I think the family moved to a new place somewhere in the US.

The leading actor was an astronaut named Matthew, he and his colleague developed a new space suit.  When the helmet was focussed on something it gave a reading as to whether they were human or not - how this would be useful for anything is not explained.

The wife makes a new friend who corrupts her somehow.  The new corrupted wife wants the dog to be put down and takes him to a vet and demands to watch the operation happen.  The vet refuses and calls Matthew to discuss the odd request with him.

In the finale Matthew figures out what is happening and puts on the space suit to rescue his wife from some kind of hell.  The 'friend' tells him he cannot and that she will punish him etc but it turns out that she actually has no power at all, she is just a good liar.  He goes to 'hell' and finds his wife playing the piano and rescues her.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The movie was [Invitation to Hell (1984)](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0087480) with Robert Urich and Susan Lucci (as the devil).

Comment: Aha main character called Matt, family moves, works on space suit, weird cult ... not the one though - only joking, that's it, thanks :-)